# expanding expression for expectation of conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, variance

Let $u,v$ be random variables with $u$ being related to $v$.

The expression is $\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left(\left(u - \mathbb{E}(u|v)\right)^{2} \right)\right | v]$.

Expanding the expression in the second outer nested expectation $\mathbb{E}$ seems trivial:

$(\left(u - \mathbb{E}(u|v)\right)^{2} = u^{2} - 2u\mathbb{E}(\left(u|v\right) + \left(\mathbb{E}\left(u|v\right)\right)^{2}$

$\rightarrow \mathbb{E}\left(\left(u - \mathbb{E}(u|v)\right)^{2} |v\right)$ =
$\mathbb{E}\left(u^{2}|v\right) -2\left(u \mathbb{E}\left(u|v\right)|v\right) + \mathbb{E}\left( \left(\mathbb{E}\left(u|v\right)\right)^{2} | v\right)$

I'm stuck at this point and would welcome some hints or identities to get me through.

Comment: $\mathbb E(uf(v)|v)=\mathbb E(u|v)\times f(v)$ for measurable $f$. You can apply that on $f(v)=\mathbb E(u|v)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$E\left[E\left(\left(U - E[U\mid V]\right)^{2} \right)\mid V\right]= E\left[\left(U - E[U\mid V]\right)^{2} \right]$$
But I think what you want to ask is:
$$Var[U\mid V]=E\left[(U - E[U\mid V])^2\mid V\right]=$$
$$=E[U^2\mid V]-2E[UE[U\mid V]\mid V]+E[E[U\mid V]^2\mid V]=$$
$$=E[U^2\mid V]-2E[U\mid V]E[U\mid V]+E[U\mid V]^2=$$
$$=E[U^2\mid V]-E[U\mid V]^2$$